# Problem with cross-referencing with numerical lists

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a problem when applying the ref command to refer to an item in a numerical list.

**Here is an example for my problem:**

My list style make the list appear as : 1. , 2. , 3.

I put a dot after the number of the item

When I refer to any item in the list, the dot appears with the number of the item.

**The question is that how to omit the dot after the number in cross-referencing?**

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem? This does not happen with a normal `enumerate` in a document with the `article` class.

Comment: I don't know how to make a minimal working example !

I am using the enumitem package

Comment: If you follow the link, there is some information about how to prepare one. Basically, an MWE is a document where you remove everything (packages, newcommands, content etc.) that doesn't have an influence on the problem, but it should still be possible to compile. So it should start with `\documentclass`, then include any related packages and customizations, then `\begin{document}`, a short list, and a cross reference to an item in the list, where the dot should appear. And finally an `\end{document}`.

Comment: First, I really want to thank you for your help :)

Second, I have solved my problem :) ... I am using the "enumitem" package and I have found the solution of my problem by reading the package documentation.

Comment: Here is an example to change the way in which the "ref" command appear in your text when you refer to an item in a list:

\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph{\alph*}),ref=\emph{\alph*}]

... This remove the right parenthesis when referring to the item

Comment: Good to hear you worked it out. (For that matter, Harish's answer has a nice example of an MWE.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ref=\arabic*` without a dot in

```
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}
```

## \def\MWE{

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item \label{enu:second}
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
According to item~\ref{enu:second} I can't tell anything about your problem!
\end{document}
```

## }

[image]

Comment: @ Harish Kumar ... I already tried to vote but it requires at least 15 reputations and I have only 8 reputations!